# Does adding a component affect KeyListeners in applets?

Tags: java, image, applet, awt, keylistener

My question is that if I add a Canvas with the add() method (the `Component java.awt.Container.add` one if there are others), will it affect any of the other things that are running, namely my KeyListener? I have been trying to figure out why all of my key presses aren't registering, and have found that they work if I do not add one instance of a canvas, but they don't work when I add it.

Unfortunately, there really isn't any way for me to not add it and still have a game, because that is the only way for me to get graphics displayed. I think this is something that others might run into, especially if they are just starting to use applets, because it is a simple part of creating a game loop, but I couldn't find any other articles on this problem. If it doesn't affect anything when I add my KeyListener, what should run the addKeyListener method?

Here is my code that I am trying to run:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class Welcome extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
private Canvas drawArea;/*Drawing Canvas*/

private final int WIDTH=300;
private final int HEIGHT=WIDTH*9/16;
private final int SCALE=2;

private BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] pixels=((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

public void init() {
    Thread t=new Thread(this);
    drawArea=new Canvas();
    setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    t.start();
    this.setSize(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
}

public void render() {
    for (int i=0; i<pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i]=i;
    }

    Graphics g=bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE, this);
    g.dispose();
    if (!bufferStrategy.contentsLost()) {
        bufferStrategy.show();
    }
}

public void update() {

}

public void run() {

    //drawArea.setSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
    add(drawArea);//WORKS WITHOUT THIS LINE OF CODE, BUT NOT WITH IT
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Here");
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Here");

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Here");

}

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance. Also, if I did anything wrong in this, feel free to let me know.

Comment: It could be that when you add the new panel, focus goes to that panel. The component that the listener is added to must be in focus. After adding the panel, try calling `component.requestFocus()` on the component containing the listener

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed the problem completely. For anyone else with the same problem, you have to do drawArea.addKeyListener(this), and then drawArea.requestFocus(). Again, thanks so much!

Comment: @VinceEmigh or WiErD0 post it as an answer, as many people who run across this site will fail to look at the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

The component that contains the listener is losing focus when you add the new component. For listeners to work, that component with the listener must be the focus owner.

If you need a certain component to be the focus owner, you can have thay component request focus using `component.requestFocus();`.

In your question, you have the listener to your applet, but after adding the `drawArea` component, your `drawArea` canvas gained focus. Since your `drawArea` didnt have a listener on it, and it was focus owner, no key events were fired. Either add the keylistener to the `drawArea`, or have your applet `requestFocus()` (although, each time you click on your `drawArea`, it will become focus owner once again. I highly suggest adding the lodtener to your `drawArea` because of this (or use Key Bindings)